# How can I get the relative position of a static object to another device with IMU?

Tags: slam, localization, android, dead-reckoning

I want to be able to search for an lost RFID, in a room. I have an [RFID scanner](https://www.convergence.com.hk/cs108/) (hand held) and an Android phone with typical sensors (gravity, acceleration, gyroscpose, etc.).  I also have RSSI and phase readings from the RFID scanner. I've already programmed these to work together and where it acts like a [geiger counter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geiger_counter), basically beeping stronger as I get closer to an RFID. The last thing I would like to program a 3D COMPASS that shows which direction the RFID is, i.e. point up, down, left, right.

I'm want to figure out how I can get x,y,z coordinates of the RFID in a world space. This is so I can program the compass to point to the RFID.

I plan to train an AI model to use all the real sensor information from these devices to build a predictive model to find the the RFID in the world space. The problem is I need gather the training data, i.e. I need to gather training data by recording an RFID's position in the world space and record the other sensor information.

As I'm completly new to the localization field, I'm not sure whats the best way to gather the localization of the RFID relative to the scanner. I looked into deadreckoning and SLAM, maybe to predict the position of the RFID and the position of the scanner.

What would be a recommended way to solve this problem?